# Given $X$, how can we choose $Y$ to make $X+Y$ normally distributed?

Tags: probability, distributions, normal-distribution, random-variable

Given an arbitrary random variable $X$, under what conditions is it possible to choose $Y$ so that the sum $X+Y$ is normally distributed?

Comment: Is this a self-study question? If so, is it connected to moment-generating functions?

Comment: Will $Y$ be independent of $X$?  Presumably you want to stipulate that, for otherwise the solution is trivial.  And when $X$ and $Y$ are independent, one might be tempted to think the only solutions are when $X$ and $Y$ are both normal--but that's not the case.  For instance, when $X$ and $Y$ are iid standard normal, then $|X| + -|Y|$ is normal even though neither $|X|$ nor $-|Y|$ is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always possible. Just define $Y = Z - X$, where $Z$ is any normally distributed random variable. Then $X + Y = X + Z - X = Z$.

Comment: I suspect you have a different interpretation of the OP's intent than I take from the question.  I think the intent is to specify the distribution of $X$ (i.e. that $X\sim F$), not to specify that $X$ takes some particular value (that $X=x$). If that's the case I don't think this works.